# Matplotlib only graph dates in the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I plot the graph with only the dates in my DataFrame? I'm getting weekends and holidays which are not in the DataFrame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web 
import datetime
data = web.DataReader("SPY",'yahoo', '2019-02-12','2019-02-19')
data.Close.plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web 
import datetime
df = web.DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo', '2019-02-12','2019-02-19')
df = df.reset_index()
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
```

**DataFrame**

```
>>> df
    Date        High        Low         Open        Close       Volume      Adj Close
0   2019-02-12  274.519989  272.339996  272.420013  274.100006  72270200    274.100006
1   2019-02-13  275.929993  274.559998  275.029999  274.989990  65277200    274.989990
2   2019-02-14  275.640015  272.869995  273.779999  274.380005  83234400    274.380005
3   2019-02-15  277.410004  276.130005  276.359985  277.369995  97088700    277.369995
4   2019-02-19  278.579987  276.470001  276.480011  277.850006  59120800    277.850006
```

**Plot**

```
ax = df['Close'].plot(marker='o')
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Date']);
```

[image: Plot]